# saving a variable as a text file name

Tags: python, variables, text-files, filenames

I'm creating a program that involves storing a team name and stats to a text file and i want to call the text file the name of the team that the user enters. At the moment it works but all teams are stored to a single text file.

code:

```
import random

def TheTeams (name):
with open("the_teams.txt, "a+") as t:
        t.write (name)
        t.write ("\n")
        
        
def NewPlayer (pname):
    at = int(input("enter your players attack 1-10 "))
    de = int(input("enter your players defence 1-10 "))
    if at >10:
        print ("NO")
        at = random.randint(1,5)
    if de >10:
        print ("NO")
        de = random.randint(1,5)
        

        
    with open("the teamss.txt", "a") as t:
        t.write (pname)
        t.write (" ")
        t.write ('%d' % at)
        t.write (" ")
        t.write ('%d' % de)
        t.write ("\n")

for i in range (1,7):
    pname = input("enter your players name ")
    NewPlayer (pname)
    
print ("""      Welcome to the ice hockey game
you will create your own team and try to score against your opponent
your teams are stored for future use

""")

n_team1 = input("player 1 do you want to create a new team ")

if n_team1 == "yes":
    team = input("enter your team name ")
    TheTeams (team)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the updated version of your code brother:

```py
import random

def TheTeams (name):
  file_name = "./" + name + ".txt" # This is the code that will create the file

  with open(file_name, "a+") as t:
    t.write (name)
    t.write ("\n")
            
def NewPlayer (pname):
  at = int(input("enter your players attack 1-10 "))
  de = int(input("enter your players defence 1-10 "))
  if at >10:
      print ("NO")
      at = random.randint(1,5)
  if de >10:
      print ("NO")
      de = random.randint(1,5)
          
  with open("the teamss.txt", "a") as t:
      t.write (pname)
      t.write (" ")
      t.write ('%d' % at)
      t.write (" ")
      t.write ('%d' % de)
      t.write ("\n")

  for i in range (1,7):
      pname = input("enter your players name ")
      NewPlayer (pname)
        
print ("""      Welcome to the ice hockey game
you will create your own team and try to score against your opponent
your teams are stored for future use

""")
    
n_team1 = input("player 1 do you want to create a new team ")

if n_team1 == "yes":
    team = input("enter your team name ")
    TheTeams (team)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just do the same thing you've done for the player's name. Ask for input and pass it in as a variable for the file's name.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: and before creating or opening any file using name provided by the user, you Really (yes, Really) want to sanitize input - at least encode it to ascii and remove any special characters (even better - keep only alphanumeric characters) and limit possible length - otherwise it will be security issue soon.